# Bottom align figures in beamer columns

Tags: beamer, floats, columns

I'm trying to bottom align align figures A and C in the MWE provided but I'm failing. Does anyone know how to do this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Madrid}
}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

\section{First Section} 

\subsection{Measurement methods}
\begin{frame}

\begin{columns}
    \column{.5\linewidth}
    \textbf{Connections}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Direct connection to unknown system
        \item Series connection between source and load
        \item Parallel connection between source and load 
    \end{itemize}
    \vspace{\fill}
    \null
    \vfill
    \begin{figure}[b]
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:imu}
    \end{figure}

    \column{.5\linewidth}
    \begin{figure}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:voltage}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth]{example-image-c}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:current}
    \end{figure}

\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

With `\begin{columns}[b]` you'll get bottom aligned columns.

Off-topic:

- you don't need `\usepackage{graphicx}` with beamer
- your columns are too wide, as there is some space between them. Either make them smaller (e.g. `.48\textwidth`) or specify `\begin{columns}[b,onlytextwidth]`
- floating options for figures, such as `\begin{figure}[b]` don't make sense in a document class which does not have floats.

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Madrid}
}


%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

\section{First Section} 

\subsection{Measurement methods}
\begin{frame}

\begin{columns}[b]
    \column{.48\linewidth}
    \textbf{Connections}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Direct connection to unknown system
        \item Series connection between source and load
        \item Parallel connection between source and load 
    \end{itemize}
    \vspace{\fill}
    \null
    \vfill
    \begin{figure}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:imu}
    \end{figure}

    \column{.48\linewidth}
    \begin{figure}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:voltage}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth]{example-image-c}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:current}
    \end{figure}

\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

To only align the two lower images at the bottom while keeping top alignment for the text and the other image, split it into multiple `coloumns` environments:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Madrid}
}


%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

\section{First Section} 

\subsection{Measurement methods}
\begin{frame}

\begin{columns}[T,onlytextwidth]
    \begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
      \textbf{Connections}
      \begin{itemize}
          \item Direct connection to unknown system
          \item Series connection between source and load
          \item Parallel connection between source and load 
      \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
    \begin{figure}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:voltage}
    \end{figure}        
    \end{column}
\end{columns}

\begin{columns}[b,onlytextwidth]
    \begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
    \begin{figure}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:imu}
    \end{figure}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
    \begin{figure}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth]{example-image-c}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:current}
    \end{figure}        
    \end{column}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This aligns the bottom figures but I also get the text that moves down as well. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: @MarkoP Please see my second solution.